# Serialize data in django restframework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I get this following data through a POST request in Django restframework.
I need to serialize this data and this data contains data for multiple models.

```
data={'admin-1':
    {'first_name':'john'
    ,'last_name':'white'
    ,'job_title':'CEO'
    ,'email':'test1@gmail.com'
    },
'admin-2':
    {'first_name':'lisa'
    ,'last_name':'markel'
    ,'job_title':'CEO'
    ,'email':'test2@gmail.com'
    },
'company-detail':{'description':'We are a renowned engineering company'
,'size':'1-10'
,'industry':'Engineering'
,'url':'http://try.com'
,'logo':''
,'addr1':'1280 wick ter'
,'addr2':'1600'
,'city':'rkville'
,'state':'md'
,'zip_cd':'12000'
,'phone_number_1':'408-393-254'
,'phone_number_2':'408-393-221'}

r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-company-profile/',data=data)
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

Here is the CreateAPI view -

```
class CompanyCreateApiView(CreateAPIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'request ==', request
        print 'request.data == ', request.data['admin-2']

        import json
        print json.loads(request.data)

        data=json.dumps({'status':'success'})
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I basically need to de-serialize the data but get this error.

> request == 
>       request.data ==  job_title
>       Internal Server Error: /api/create-company-profile/
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/Users/prem/.virtualenvs/ghost/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 111, in get_response
>           response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>         File "/Users/prem/.virtualenvs/ghost/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py",
>   line 57, in wrapped_view
>           return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/Users/prem/.virtualenvs/ghost/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
>   line 69, in view
>           return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>         File "/Users/prem/.virtualenvs/ghost/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
>   line 452, in dispatch
>           response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>         File "/Users/prem/.virtualenvs/ghost/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
>   line 449, in dispatch
>           response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>         File "/Users/prem/Documents/Ghost/positionmatch-new/menkes-server-master/menkesserver/human_resources/views.py",
>   line 81, in post
>           print json.loads(request.data)
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py",
>   line 338, in loads
>           return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>         File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py",
>   line 365, in decode
>           obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>       TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no need to manually decode the POST data in your view. As long as you are using the `JSONParser`, as described in the [parsers documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/), `request.data` should already be fully parsed for you.

Additionally, it looks like the request you're sending to the view is probably not acting how you think. If you want to send JSON data with requests, you need to be a little more explicit. As shown in the example in the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

```
>>> import json
>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: When I display the request.data, I don't get the full data thats been posted .It looks like truncated but not sure......Here is the printed data...request.data ==  {u'admin-1': u'job_title', u'company-detail': u'zip_cd', u'admin-2': u'job_title'}

Comment: You should double check the data that you are sending in the request. I tried copying and pasting what you presented here into a Python shell, and it was missing a trailing `}`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include information on properly encoding your request